# Preferred method for persist session token on the server with RIA Services?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm using an AuthenticationService derived from AuthenticationBase in the standard business application template for RIA Services and using Forms authentication.  I have my own CustomPrincipal that is created by my security infrastructure that I assign to Thread.CurrentPrincipal, so that it can be used by other service calls:

```
protected override bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    try
    {
        using (LoginService service = new LoginService())
        {
            SessionInfo info = service.Login(userName, password);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = info.User;
            SessionCache.Instance.Save(info);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        return false;
     }   
}
```

I've discovered, however, when other (non-authentication) RIA services are called, the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is reset to a GenericPrincipal object, so upon initialization of the other services, I override the Initialize() method of the domain service and set Thread.CurrentPrincipal by looking up the login in a session cache:

```
public override void Initialize(DomainServiceContext context)
{
    base.Initialize(context);
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        SessionInfo info = SessionCache.Instance.FindByUsername(context.User.Identity.Name);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = info.User;
    }
}
```

Right now this lookup is being done by Username, because it is easily accessible in the GenericPrincipal, but I'd prefer that I could do the lookup via a session token.  Is there a method with RIA services to easily persist a session token on the server during the lifetime of the session?  I know I could put this session token in a cookie in the browser to persist it, but it seems like there should be a simpler method to persist a session token across the lifetime of the session.  Perhaps the cookie method is the best way to do this, but I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: As per [this](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2011/04/13/MIX11Releases.aspx) announcement for RIA Services 1.0 SP2, it appears there's a new OperationTag which may help address this problem.

Comment: Looks like OperationTag was cut: http://varunpuranik.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/operationtagits-demise-and-workarounds/